# how do i insert data into my H2 database using a form

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.0, h2

How do i insert data into my H2 database using a form in the play framework. im new to play and the h2 database. i can send the data and display it on the next webpage using a form but i dont know how to put it in the database, and cant seem to find any good information on the internet.

i already made a connection using:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password=""
```

this is the code i used to send the data to the next webpage
Application.conf:

```
  val form = Form(
  tuple(
  "firstname" -> nonEmptyText(1),
  "midname"  ->  optional(text),
  "lastname" -> nonEmptyText(1),
  "number" -> text,
  "email" -> email
  )
  )

  def submit = Action { implicit request =>
  val (firstname, midname, lastname, number, email) = form.bindFromRequest.get
  Ok(("Hi %s %s %s\nTelefoonnummer: %s\nEmail: %s").format(firstname, midname, lastname, number, email))

}
```

form and route(nothing special here):

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="@routes.Application.formSubmit()">

GET     /formSubmit                 controllers.Application.formLogin()
POST    /formSubmit                 controllers.Application.submit()
```

[h2-browser loginscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XJGE.png)

i hope that this is enough information to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create a schema to use it. 
Then enable play database evolutions in your `application.conf` to create tables and etc. You can also do it manually.

For more details about [evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions)

After db is configured and created; you can choose between `Anorm`, `Slick` or `Jdbc api` for database operations.

I prefer [Anorm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm)

Here is a sample code for inserting data;

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    val id: Option[Long] = 
        SQL("INSERT INTO City(name, country) values ({name}, {country})")
        .on('name -> "Cambridge", 'country -> "New Zealand").executeInsert()
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why unmarked this as answer? So maybe I can improve it.

Comment: i made a schema and got the 'your database needs evolution' warning. i changed the script so it doesnt drop the User table, but it doesnt change anything. do i have the wrong database name or something?
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:~/test
application.conf: db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
i used the User schema from the evolutions link you gave me.
i just changed the DROP TABLE USER to DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST

Comment: ^ doesnt change anything in the database is what i meant to say

Comment: play saves changes in play_evolutions table so once it applied  0.sql, It'll never run it again. You should have incremental sql changes file like 1.sql 2.sql or you can truncate table so play applies changes from beginning.

Comment: so i just need to create a new sql file everytime i want to add a script?